# Python dynamic functions with keyword arguments avoid unused parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings, keyword-argument

I have a part of code in python, which calls dynamically different functions, where I always want to pass 3 different arguments. However, these functions, might not always need to use those 3 different arguments.
Here is a very simple code that shows the issue:

```
def test_keyword_args():
    def fn1(a, b, c):
        return a + b

    def fn2(a, b, c):
        return a + c

    def fn3(a, b, c):
        return b + c

    obj = {
        'a': fn1,
        'b': fn2,
        'c': fn3,
    }

    for key in obj:
        value = obj[key](a=1, b=2, c=3)
        if key == 'a':
            assert value == 3
        if key == 'b':
            assert value == 4
        if key == 'c':
            assert value == 5
```

How can I always call same function `obj[key](a=1,b=2,c=3)` passing this keyword arguments, and avoid complains about unused parameters? (c not used in fn1, b not used in fn2, a not used in fn3)

I can imagine suppressing warnings would do the trick, but I do not think it is the appropriate solution

I am using Python 3.7.3

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington, I am using Python 3.7.3, sorry, I will post it in the question too! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define arguments as keyword only by prefixing the argument list with `*`, you can then avoid the unused parameter warnings by naming a parameter `_`. Using `**_` allows us to ignore any keyword arguments not in our named parameters

```
def fn1(*, a, b, **_):
    return a + b

def fn2(*, a, c, **_):
    return a + c

def fn3(*, b, c, **_):
    return b + c
```

Comment: Perfect approach! Exactly what I was looking for! As soon as I can accept your answer I will. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You may use `kwargs` to pass key word arguments to a function. In such case `kwargs` is the dictionary with named arguments passed to function.

```
def fn1(a, b, **kwargs):
    return a + b
```

You can pass anything to this function in format `fn1(a_value, b_value, any_parameter_1=100, any_parameter_2=100)` etc. In function you receive your variables `a` and `b` and also `kwargs` dictionary with following content

```
{
    "any_parameter_1": 100,
    "any_parameter_2": 1000,
}
```

Also you may pass all variables as kwargs

```
def fn1(**kwargs):
    return kwargs["a"] + kwargs["b"]
```

But you need to assign names to your parameters like this `fn1(a=a_value, b=b_value, any_parameter_1=100, any_parameter_2=100)` and `kwargs` dictionary will looks like

```
{
    "a": a_value,
    "b": b_value,
    "any_parameter_1": 100,
    "any_parameter_2": 1000,
}
```